# How to display text field in webform block

Tags: webforms

Webform content type has two text fields. 
I added a webform node with one component.
I can see the both text fields when I visit the webform node page. After I display the webform as a block, I can only see the webform component but block does not display the fields.

How can I display the text fields in webform block?

Comment: The Webform content type only has one text field by default. Have you added an additional field to the content type or are these text field in the form itself?

Comment: Structure > content type > webform > added two additional text fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view that will display the form. While creating the view, be sure that the "create a block" option is checked. You'll also want the view to display the full post and you'll need to set filters so only the single form is displayed.